# What explains this outcome using fread() in C++?

Tags: c++, io, fread

I'm reading a text file consisting of the following 17 characters: *Hello! What's up?*

Experimenting with different sized reads using fread(), I'm seeing some strange results.

```
char* buffer = new char[17];

{...}

fread(buffer, 17, 1, file);
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

- Prints `Hello! What's up?���`

```
char* buffer = new char[33];

{...}

fread(buffer, 33, 1, file);
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

- Prints `Hello! What's up?`

Reading anywhere from 17-32 bytes produces these mystery characters. If the size of the file is 17 bytes, what explains the mystery characters printed with a read size of 17 bytes?

Comment: In the first one, there is no string terminator in the array. 17 elements and 17 characters, there is no room. In the second one, there was a string terminator in the array by chance. The function `fread` is usually used to read binary data, not text. Anyway, the code is C++ not C as tagged.

Comment: Tantillom Change tag to C++ or code to valid C.

Comment: How are you expecting the printing code to know how many characters to print?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is missing string terminator NULL at the end of string

```
char* buffer = new char[18];

{...}

fread(buffer, 17, 1, file);
buffer[17] = '\0';
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```